# C++ Modern OpenGL - Calculate Vertex Normals

Tags: opengl, c++, normals

I'm learning modern OpenGL and i just got started so go easy on me :).
Right now im trying to understand normals but im having some difficulties.
On my program i have this class which i use to draw primitives and i also 
implemented the assimp model loader which uses this class to load and draw meshes.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>

#include "../c_renderer.h"
#include "../c_component.h"
#include "../utils/texture2d.h"

struct Vertex
{
public:
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 texcoords;

    Vertex()
    {
        color       = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        texcoords   = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    }


    Vertex(const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec2& texcoords)
    {
        this->position = position;
        this->texcoords = texcoords;
        //How to calculate normal ???
        this->normal = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
    }
};

class C_MeshFilter : public C_Component
{
private:
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo;
    GLuint ebo;

    std::vector<Vertex>         m_vertices;
    std::vector<GLuint>         m_indices;
    std::vector<Texture2D>      m_textures;
public:
    C_MeshFilter()
    {
        C_Component::setDrawable(true);
    }

    C_MeshFilter(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices)
    {
        C_Component::setDrawable(true);

        m_vertices  = vertices;
        m_indices   = indices;

        compile();
    }

    C_MeshFilter(std::vector<Vertex> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices, std::vector<Texture2D> textures)
    {
        C_Component::setDrawable(true);

        m_vertices  = vertices;
        m_indices   = indices;
        m_textures  = textures;

        compile();
    }


    C_MeshFilter& setVertices(std::vector<Vertex> vertices)
    {
        m_vertices = vertices;
        return *this;
    }

    C_MeshFilter& setIndices(std::vector<GLuint> indices)
    {
        m_indices = indices;
        return *this;
    }

    C_MeshFilter& setTextures(std::vector<Texture2D> textures)
    {
        m_textures = textures;
        return *this;
    }

    C_MeshFilter& setVertex(const Vertex vertex)
    {
        m_vertices.push_back(vertex);
        return *this;
    }

    C_MeshFilter& setTexture(const Texture2D& texture)
    {
        m_textures.push_back(texture);
        return *this;
    }

    void compile()
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &m_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex,  color));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoords));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    void draw(C_Renderer renderer)
    {
        GLuint diffuseNumber = 1;
        GLuint specularNumber = 1;


        for (GLuint i = 0; i < m_textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);

            std::string uniformNo;
            std::string texname = m_textures[i].getTextureType();

            if (texname == "texture_diffuse")
            {
                uniformNo = std::to_string(diffuseNumber++);
            }
            else if (texname == "texture_specular")
            {
                uniformNo = std::to_string(specularNumber++);
            }

            GLuint uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderer.getShaderProgram(), (texname + uniformNo).c_str());
            glUniform1i(uniformLoc, i);

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[i].getTexture());
        }

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)m_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);


        for (GLuint i = 0; i < m_textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

But when i try to draw simple primitives like this

```
C_Entity crate;
crate.addComponent<C_MeshFilter>()
    .setVertex(Vertex(glm::vec3(0.5f,   0.5f,  0.0f),   glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f)))
    .setVertex(Vertex(glm::vec3(0.5f,  -0.5f,  0.0f),   glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)))
    .setVertex(Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f),   glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f)))
    .setVertex(Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f),   glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f)))
    .setIndices(std::vector<Gluint> { 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3 })
    .setTexture(Texture2D("data/textures/crate.png", "texture_diffuse"))
    .compile();
```

I get weird results when lighting is applied.
How to calculate the normal vector per vertex

```
Vertex(const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec2& texcoords)
        {
            this->position = position;
            this->texcoords = texcoords;
            //How to calculate normal ???
            this->normal = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
        }
```

Comment: This website might help you visualize the normal vector, http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/

Comment: @user3730788 normal maps are not the same as vector normals